# Как добавить значение типа LocalDate в базу данных при помощи PreparedStatement

Tags: java, sql, preparedstatement

Есть метод `add(Employee employee)` который принимает `employee`. У этого `employee` есть разные данные, включая дату приёма на работу типа `LocalDate.now()`.

```
String sql = "insert into employee values (?, ...)";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setDate(1, Date.valueOf(employee.getHired()));
```

Этот `employeе` хочу добавить в базу данных. При добавление даты нету метода setLocalDate в `statement`, и попытался, преобразовать в тип Date, но пишет что такое преобразование не возможно. Как решить проблему, сделать чтоб statement получил дату типа LocalDate.

При использовании

```
statement.setObject(6, employee.getHired());
```

выдает `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion`
Может что то неправильно написал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для работы с `LocalDate` в JDBC есть методы [`setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-)/[`getObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-int-java.lang.Class-).
`LocalDate` будет преобразована в тип `DATE` SQL.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject (1 , myLocalDate);
```

Для получения даты из базы, нужно в аргументы `setObject` передать аргумент `class` того типа данных, которые мы хотим получить.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject ("date_column" , LocalDate.class);
```

Comment: При использовании  statement.setObject(6, employee.getHired()); , выдает java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion

Comment: Я работаю с HSQLDB, может в этом проблема

Comment: All work thanks